# Java Only half of the elements in my String Array are printed

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing

I am trying to print out every element of my Array of Strings called `Resources` along with a statement before it, and an integer after it.

It should be printed out like this:

> gather.rate dispenser Wood 10

First off, here is my code:

```
private String[] Resources =  { "Explosives", "Animal Fat", "Cooked Fish",
        "Raw Fish", "Low Grade Fuel", "Granola Bar", "Gun Powder", "Hemp Clone", "Hemp Seed",
        "High Quality Metal Ore", "Burned Human Meat", "Cooked Human Meat", "Raw Human Meat",
        "Spoiled Human Meat", "Leather", "Burnt Bear Meat", "Bear Meat Cooked", "Bear Meat",
        "Burned Pork", "Cooked Pork", "Pork", "Burned Wolf Meat", "Cooked Wolf Meat", 
        "Raw Wolf Meat", "Spoiled Wolf Meat", "Metal Fragments", "Metal Ore","High Quality Metal",
        "Minnows", "Mushroom", "Paper", "Pumpkin", "Pumpkin Plant Clone", "Pumpkin Seed",
        "Research Paper", "Salt Water", "Human Skull", "Wolf Skull", "Small Trout", "Small Water Bottle",
        "Stones", "Sulfur", "Sulfur Ore", "Targeting Computer", "Water", "Water Jug", "Wood", "Apple", 
        "Rotten Apple", "Battery - Small", "Black Raspberries", "Blueberries","Bone Fragments", 
        "Cactus Flesh", "Can of Beans", "Empty Can Of Beans", "Can of Tuna", "Candy Cane", "CCTV Camera", 
        "Charcoal", "Burned Chicken", "Cooked Chicken", "Raw Chicken Breast", "Spoiled Chicken", "Chocolate Bar",
        "Cloth", "Coal :(", "Corn", "Corn Clone", "Corn Seed", "Crude Oil" };

private int multiplier;

public Miserum(int value)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    multiplier = value;
}

public void DoThis(){
    String result = " ";
    for(int x = 0; x < Resources.length; x++){
        result = "gather.rate dispenser " + Resources[x] + " " + multiplier;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

So there are about 71 elements in my `String[] Resources`.

When I run the `DoThis()` method, it prints about 46 elements and it doesn't even start at the beginning, it starts at

> Spoiled Wolf Meat.

Why might this be? It completely spaces over the first elements and starts printing from the middle.

I don't think that is what my code is saying to do, but clearly there's something wrong.

IF you have a better way to do this/fix to my solution, please spill the beans.

*And I am using the BlueJ IDE

Comment: working fine by me http://ideone.com/xhNVpc

Comment: Are you sure it is not writing all of them? Can your screen display all of the lnies at once? Perhaps the first items are rolled off the top of your screen and you only see the bottom ones

Comment: Are you running your program in an IDE? Which one (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or some other)? Or from a command prompt (DOS prompt or shell)?

Comment: Perhaps set a breakpoint in your IDE in the loop and watch it. It certainly looks ok. As others have said, perhaps it's writing everything, but you're not able to see it all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to print the results to a file and not to the console.
This way you can ascertain whether the problem is in the algorithm or just your console (as mentioned in the comments).